# Running cd on many macOS terminals with one command

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I often open two or three windows of the macOS terminal in a tiled configuration. Sometimes I want to `cd` into a particular directory in all of them.

The best idea I have it to try to write to `/dev/ttys00*`, for example,

```
echo -ne "echo hello\x0a\x0d" > /dev/ttys000
```

This will show up on the other terminal but the bytes at the end aren't triggering the command to be accepted. Is there a byte sequence that does this? (It wouldn't surprise me if there's not, for security reasons.) Btw, you can run `tty` to discover what device a particular window is mapped to.

I've also tried setting the `$PWD` variable but it doesn't seem to actually change the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This will show up on the other terminal but the bytes at the end aren't triggering the command to be accepted.

**Every tty device has two ends,** like a pipe. What you write to one end *does not loop back*, but comes out through the other end instead. For example, with serial ports you have `/dev/ttyS*` on the one end, and the physical serial port on the other end. What you write to `/dev/ttyS0` is sent over the wire.

Likewise, for pseudo-terminals (ptys), you have `/dev/ttys*` going to a nameless "pty master" device which is managed by the terminal app. When you write something to `/dev/ttys000`, it is *not* received by the shell as input at all, because the shell is attached to the *same* 'slave' side of the pty. Instead, the write is received by the *terminal app* which holds the corresponding pty master' fd, and shown as if it were program *output*.

(Some older BSDs, where the ptys are named `/dev/ttyP*`, have a corresponding `/dev/ptyP*` device for the master end, but I don't think macOS has an equivalent. Linux certainly doesn't – every time you open `/dev/ptmx` there, you get a *new* pty pair allocated.)

---

So how to achieve what you want?

- You could try to find an escape sequence that asks the terminal to return something back as input. That used to exist (e.g. there was a "tell me the current window title" sequence), but nearly all terminals disable it for security reasons: for example, if you `cat` a malicious file, it could set the terminal title and immediately ask for it back, thus running a command.
- You could ask the kernel to fake the input. On Linux there is `ioctl(TIOCSTI)` which is can be used by tools like [writevt](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=writevt); it *does* loop back the input to all other programs connected to the same end of a tty. I'm not sure if it works on macOS.
- You could look into other automation methods. If I remember correctly, macOS has [the "Automator" app](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/10/25/automating-terminal-tasks-on-osx) and AppleScript. Other systems might have tools which hook into the accessibility features (the way a virtual keyboard would).